# How to get PUT request data using Java Play Framework 2.0.3 and easyXDM

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to call my own web service (Java Play 2.0.3) from a web application using easyXDM

this is my code on the client side (web):

```
  var formValues = {
           email: $('#editUserEmail').val(),
           first_name: $('#editUserFirstName').val(),
           last_name: $('#editUserLastName').val()
  };

  this.xhr.request({
           url: "http://restserver.dev:9000/users/" + this.model.get('id'),
           method: "PUT",
           data: formValues
        }, function(response){
           console.log(response.data);

           var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.data);

           if (jsonResponse.status == 'success'){
              alert("saved successfully");
           }

        });
```

Here is code for the server (Java) :

```
  final Map<String, String[]> values = request().body()
    .asFormUrlEncoded();

    // validating
    if (values.containsKey("first_name"))
        db_user.first_name  = values.get("first_name")[0];
    if (values.containsKey("last_name"))
        db_user.last_name = values.get("last_name")[0];
    if (values.containsKey("email"))
        db_user.email = values.get("email")[0];
```

It works fine for POST method, but whenever I tried using PUT method, somehow the server can't get the PUT request body data (values is null). I change it to POST with the same code and it works fine.
Did I do something wrong on the client or server side?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified your `routes` file accordingly ?

Comment: yes..the routes are fine, I tried it with curl and the server would pick up  the data values just fine. I am thinking that I am doing something wrong with easyXDM.

Comment: try to check if the values are sent correctly in your request using your browser inspector ("Network" tab on Google Chrome)

Comment: thanks! Using POST the data is in the form data part on the html request, but using PUT it is in the query string part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember not all browsers support **PUT** on Ajax requests. This may the reason you are having an issue here. For cross-browser compatibility, you should stick to GET/POST on Ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, apparently thats what happening on my browser, using POST the data is in the form data part on the html request, but using PUT it is in the query string part.
Is there a workaround for this or i just have to stick with get/post on ajax call?

Comment: As far as I know it depends on the browser, better stick to GET/POST for safety